# Google charts - draw chart with variable parameters

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I was trying to create a chart using google charts with some parameters passed to that function. I am using those parameters to populate the data. But it is not working. Is it possible to make that function with parameters as i dont know what happens inside google.charts.setOnCallback() method?

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart(scoreForEachSkill, skillList) {

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string','Skill');
data.addColumn('number','Score');
for(var i=0;i< scoreForEachSkill.length;i++)
{
    data.addRow(skillList[i],scoreForEachSkill[i]);
}

var options = {'title':'Skills', 'width':610, 'height':390};
var chart = new 
google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('pieChart'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

The html and css part

```
<div id="pieChart" style="margin-left:-10px;margin-right:-10px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the load callback doesn't accept any parameters,
to handle, just use an *in between* function...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
});

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
  drawChart(score, skill);
});
```

the callback can also be placed directly in the load statement...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    drawChart(score, skill);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

note: the callback only needs to be called once per page load,
not each time you want to draw a chart,
so you could do something like this...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    drawChart(score1, skill1);
    drawChart(score2, skill2);
    drawChart(score3, skill3);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```